# How to return last comment?

Tags: python, django, templates

I have probably a small problem. Namely how can i extract a last comment when i use 'post.comments.all'

```
class CommentPost(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(Profil, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      post = models.ForeignKey(Posty, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="comments")
      content1 = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False)
      date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
      date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.content1)


class Posty(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
   sub_title = models.SlugField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
   content = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False)
   image = models.ImageField(default="avatar.png",upload_to="images", validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['png','jpg','jpeg'])])
   author = models.ForeignKey(Profil, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
   published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   T_or_F = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   likes = models.ManyToManyField(Profil, related_name='liked')
   unlikes = models.ManyToManyField(Profil, related_name='unlikes')
   created_tags = models.ForeignKey('Tags', blank=True, null=True, related_name='tagi', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Views

```
    tag = request.GET.get('tag')
if tag == None:
    my_tag = Posty.objects.all
    print(my_tag)
else:
    my_tag = Posty.objects.filter(created_tags__tag=tag)
    print(my_tag)
```

If i tried use '[:1]' or last, this dont work.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with the last Post? You seem to already have the `Post` since you use `post.comments.all()`?

Comment: Oh my bad, i mean  last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the last comment with:

```
post.comments.latest('date_posted')
```

or if you want the latest per `date_updated`, you use:

```
post.comments.latest('date_updated')
```

If you want to obtain the last comment per post, you can work with a `Prefetch` object:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

posts = Posty.objects.annotate(
    latest_comment=Subquery(
        CommentPost.objects.filter(
            post=OuterRef('pk')
        ).values('content1').order_by('-date_posted')[:1]
    )
)
```

then in the template, you can render with:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.last_comment }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Could not parse the remainder: '('date_posted')' from 'post.comments.latest('date_posted')'

Comment: @ProtoN: you can not use this in the template. You should do this in the view. Django templates deliberately restrict the syntax such that method calls (with parameters) are *not* allowed.

Comment: I know, but when i tried in view. i also got errors ;3
'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'latest'

Comment: @ProtoN: it looks like `post` is not a `Post` object, but a reference to the `Post` class.

Comment: So i couldn't return last comment? No way? If i tried {% for com in post.comments.all  %} its return all comments.

                {% for post in my_tag %}<br/>
                    {% for com in post.comments.all  %}
                        {{com.content1}}
                    {% endfor %}<hr/>
                {% endfor %}

Comment: @ProtoN: what is your view trying to achieve? Some sort of listview where you show *multiple* posts?

Comment: I try got,  a last comment from post. I need to show what the last user write and who was this. I added a illustrative photo.

Comment: @ProtoN: you can annotate the `Posty`s in the view, and then render the `.last_comment` in the template.